# how can i get a message from TCP/IP and continously print it in a text frame

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, tcp

i am trying to get message from a tcp/ip

i used this code coped  from http://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#server

import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
try:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

    # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(16)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
        if data:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
            connection.sendall(data)
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
            break

finally:
    # Clean up the connection
    connection.close()
```

client

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#client

import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('192.168.1.88', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
try:
    sock.connect(server_address)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting good'
finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting failed' #% server_address

try:

    # Send data
    message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
    sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for the response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(16)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

put i want to enter the message from text box 
and receive it in a text box too

i tried to use python `GTK` 
put i cant do a loop

also i tried to use `Tkinter`
put also i cant use it in a loop

can any one help me ??

Comment: Why not put all your code inside a function, create a button in the GUI toolkit of your choice, and execute the function when the user clicks the button? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i want it to listen to the msg that is recieved from tcp and automatic print it on the gui @Rawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal client gui using Gtk. Sends user input to the server and puts the response into a label.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib
import socket

# create the connection
sock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 10000))


def send(button):
    text= entry.get_text() # get the text to send from the GtkEntry
    # send the stuff
    remaining= len(text)
    while True:
        sent= sock.send(text)
        remaining-= sent
        if not remaining:
            break
        text= text[sent:]
    # wait for the server's response
    response= sock.recv(50)
    # and put it into a label
    Gdk.threads_add_idle(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, label.set_text, response)

# spawn the GUI
window= Gtk.Window()
vbox= Gtk.VBox()
entry= Gtk.Entry()
button= Gtk.Button('send')
# when the user clicks the button, send something to the server
button.connect('clicked', send)
label= Gtk.Label()
vbox.pack_start(entry, False, False, 0)
vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)
vbox.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)
window.add(vbox)

window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```